# passport object undefined after being passed into function

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I have the following code in app.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const { initializePassport } = require('./passportConfig');
initializePassport(
    passport,
    email  => Account.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => Account.find(user => user._id === id)
);
```

initializePassport function:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function initializePassport (passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    console.log(passport);
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByEmail(email);
        if(user == null) {
            return done(null, false, { message: "no user with given email" });
        }
        try {
            if(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: "password incorrect" });
            }
        } catch(e) {
            return done(e);
        }
    }

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email'}, authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user._id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        return done(null, getUserById(id))
    })
}

module.exports = initializePassport();
```

I am passing the passport object that I declared in app.js to the initializePassport function, but it I am getting the following error:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email'}, authenticateUser));
         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

To verify that the object is indeed undefined, I console.log()ed it and sure enough, it prints undefined. If i am to comment out the .use() statement, the same error occurs on the .serializeUser() function.
Why is the passport object undefined and how can I pass it to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I still do not know exactly what caused the problem, but moving the initializePassport definition to app.js resolved the issue.